# ScalaTest unit test dont hit breakpoints

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

So I have a small problem on which google mainly hits wrong results.

It is very simple: I make unit-tests for scala using ScalaTest FunSuite and my breakpoints inside the tests dont hit (Intellij 2016.2.5, previous version was the same,already updates). However when I place breakpoints in code outside of my unit tests the debugger does break. Settings on the breakpoints are exactly similar (ctrl-shift-f8).

So for some mysterious reason breakpoints inside my test will never hit but outside it does (proofs the forking trick is not doing any good). The project is very new still. Running this on another machine does work somehow so I suspect it is some setting in Intellij.

I am a bit lost on this and dont feel like writing mains to hit breakpoints.

Thanks

Comment: There is a possibly related [issue logged](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11108), you can help fixing it by providing a [reproducible test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).